# Refactoring jQuery in JS issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I use jQuery frequently but I have realized that I need to understand the underlying Javascript better. I have worked out the AJAX part but am stuck on the nested functions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState;

  if (state == 'interactive') {
    $('#button').on("click", function() {
      $.getJSON(apiurl, function(json) {

        $.each(json.photos.photo, function(i, myresult) {
          apiurl_size = "https//api/myresult";
          $.getJSON(apiurl_size, function(size) {
            $.each(size.sizes.size, function(i, myresult_size) {
              if (myresult_size.width == selected_size) {
                $("#results").append('<p class="col-md-4"><a href="" ><img src="' + myresult_size.source + '"/></a></p>');
              }
            })
          })
        });
      });
    });
  } else if (state == 'complete') {
    document.getElementById('complete');
  }
}
```

What I want to know:

1. how to grab the id selector in `$('button')` since `document.getElementById('button')` returns the entire element but I cannot enact the `.on click` functionalitiy
2. breaking the `.getJSON` function out into a pure JS reusable function

Comment: And WHAT exacty do you want to know?

Comment: @ThomasJunk that is a really good point and I have updated my post with my knowledge gap questions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be someting like `var apiurl_size = "https://api/" + myresult;`? Variables aren't expanded inside strings, you have to use concatenation.

Comment: I just inserted a string haphazardly, but yes you are correct about using concatenation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$("#button").on("click", cb_function)` is analogous to `document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", cb_function)`. If you were using a selector that can match multiple elements, it's similar except that it loops over all the returned elements to add event listeners to all of them.
2. `$.getJSON(URL, cb_function)` creates an AJAX request to the URL whose `onreadystatechange` callback function essentially does:

   1. call `JSON.parse()` on the response.
   2. Call `cb_function` with the result of the parse.

A simple version would be like:

```
function getJSON(url, cb_function) {
    var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readystate == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            cb_function(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
    return xhr;
}
```

The real `$.getJSON` allows you to supply parameters to the URL, and it automatically converts from an object to the appropriate URL-encoded string to add as URL parameters. But neither of your calls has data parameters, so this definition should work for you.

Comment: Can you clarify using the elements of your explanation of `$.getJSON()` with the two used as code?

Comment: Which part of it is hard for you to translate into code? If you don't know how to code an AJAX request in plain Javascript, why don't you just stick with jQuery?

Comment: I am just trying to understand what is going on under the hood

Comment: Like I said, it just sends an AJAX request, and in the `onreadystatechange` handler it parses the JSON and then calls the function that was given to it.